# Cannot assign to read only property 'props' of #<Object> in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Cannot assign to read only property 'props' of #

I checked [#1654](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1654) with no success. Please have a look at the issue in more detail here-

[image: Screenshot of error]

Basically what I am doing is using a Navigator to move from index page to ApplistGridView page.
I see the navigation is successful(from logs) but, even before I see the screen I face this issue.

And chrome debug messages-

[image: Chrome Debug messages]

Code is posted at [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4281#issuecomment-158754387)
Haven't found a solution. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot push to props `this.props.nav.push({id: 'Applist', index: 2});` since component properties are read-only, as the error states. Props can only be derived from a parent component, but cannot be modified.

EDIT: This article is a great starting point for people confused in this matter as I was a while ago:)
https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Can you please tell me more about what "read-only" component means? I didn't make any component read-only by virtue as per my knowledge.

Comment: @bozzmob This is by default how React handles properties (props) that are passed by a parent component. Instead of using props, you can make use of states. If you want to share an object/array or such across and app, instead of passing a state to other components you can make use of Flux or Redux to share a store across your app.

Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939623/can-i-update-a-components-props-in-react-js

Comment: @Thomas -  I am also facing a similar problem but the uniqueness is that the application is working fine but when I run the test (Which I have written using jest) I am getting this error could you please help me in getting a better understanding of it

Answer (score 7):

If this is happening to you not because of **props** but because of **state**, you may be trying to do an assignment like this:

```
this.state.nav = 'whatever';
```

Remember that assignments to `state` in React should be like:

```
this.setState({
  nav: 'whatever'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You write `this.props.nav.push({id: 'Applist', index: 2});`

But `this.props` is read-only; you cannot modify it.

If you want to pass some value to the parent react component, then you can use `this.prop.onSomeEvent(value)` in a child component. Then handle the push process in the parent component.

Answer (score -4):

In file node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js
change
ts.JsxEmit.ReactJsx
to
ts.JsxEmit.ReactJSX

Comment: Never change anything in node_modules files...