# Why is an anti-pattern letting a react component to edit its own props?

Tags: reactjs, anti-patterns

I was searching for an answer to another problem and I found this answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24943743/4792548)) I'm just curious why is it that modifying its own props is an anti-pattern, and why isn't it that modifying its own state is not and anti-pattern?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089532/why-cant-i-update-props-in-react-js It's a paradigm the framework uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In react, **props** is an object of data that is **unlikely to change** in the lifecycle of the component, and **state** is data that is **likely to change** in the lifecycle of the component.

It helps create explicit rules for where developers should put things that do/do-not change.

React update pages very quickly by knowing exactly that data changes will either come strictly from a parent(as props) or come internally as state.

the exact function checks loosely if state/props are the same, then https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L881-L883

I'd recommend reading about how react "reconciles" data for changes and making updates to the dom. 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: To add another point - React treats props as immutable such that it can perform certain shallow checking optimizations during the re-render flow and bail out if there's no work to be done.

Comment: @yaycmyk it actually checks both https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L881-L883