# Update props without leaving function in React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have simple check, which I must do when user clicking the button:

```
<button 
    onClick={() => {
        this.props.validatingActions.validate(this.props.Email.Value);
        this.props.submittingActions.submitValidation(this.props.Email.IsValid);
}}>Submit</button>
```

At first, email in **Redux** store validates, then, some actions do, when email is valid or not.

The problem is, that *this.props* don't update after executing `this.props.validatingActionsvalidate`, they're only updates after leaving anonymous `onClick` function, therefore `this.props.Email.IsValid` has old value.

How can I properly update props in such situations?

Comment: Why aren't you calling validate when the user changes the email field? This can be a debounced function if you're concerned about performance.

Comment: Because this is simplified example, I have really many fields like this. What do you mean by debounced?

Comment: Debouncing a function is a way to ensure it's not called multiple times - that is to say clicking a button 5 times won't result in 5 submissions.

Can you post your action creators and reducers?

Comment: Now, i don't have them, but I understand what is it.

Comment: The problem exists because you're dispatching two actions at the same time, which is causing a race condition in your current store state. You'll likely need to use some middleware like `thunk` or `redux-saga` in order to make this work the way you'd like it to.

Comment: I'm currently using `thunk`, firstly I dispatch `request` type then `success` or `error`.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you shouldn't (and in most cases can't) change a component's own props.
Please check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939623/can-i-update-a-components-props-in-react-js) for more details.

## Answer update

Also please be aware that React `setState` is asynchronous so state changes are not made immediately after calling `setState`. And as a result props which are based on state also aren't updated immediately after dispatching an action.

When prop is updated components is re-rendered and if you need changed prop value immediately I assume it's not needed in component render function but somewhere else to decide if perform another action or not. If so it should be handled in actions: you can use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) to dispatch asynchronous or conditional actions.

Comment: I don't change them, my component props managed by `connect` function provided by `react-redux` library and 'mapStateToProps' function, whhich is responsible for mapping redux store to componeent props.

Comment: In that case, you should dispatch an action to call a state reducer to update the values you're looking to change. You can do those by using `mapDispatchtoProps` within `connect` as described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops

Comment: This is what I do, that's the main problem, that we can't have new props values inside function, without leaving it.

Comment: It's expected react behaviour

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz ok, so, what should I do then, if I my requirements break that behaviour?

Comment: Well, when props are updated components is re-rendered and if you need changed prop value immidiately I assume it's not needed in component render function but somewehere else to decide if perform some action or not. If so IMO it should be handled in actions: you can use `redux-thunk` to perform asynchronous or conditional actions. But it's really hard to provide detailed solution seeing only small piece of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Redux-Form http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/syncValidation/, when you want to work with forms

Comment: Seems good, but I can't switch to this library in current situation for most reasons, so, how about solving current problem?

Comment: This is bad advice for two reasons.  Redux-Form is complex and powerful, and not needed for most situations, and it's definitely not answering the current question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing props isn't the way to solve it.
Where is your logic for validating and submiting? Directly in the reducer?
Either do both things on the same action, or use a side effects library to do one after the other.
In any case, judging by the names of the actions, I don't see why you would use redux actions for that. Validating an input doesn't sound like a state change to me.
You should validate it with a simple function and depending if it's ok or not, act (with an action) accordingly.