# Given " Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression" in React Native when using onChangeText

Tags: react-native

My code for a component in React-Native is as follows (please note I am using native-base in case the structure looks weird):

```
class CardIntInput extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Form>
          <Item regular>
            <Label> 
              {this.props.info}:
            </Label>
            <Input
              keyboardType = 'number-pad'
              onChangeText = {(text) => {this.props.data} = text}
            />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

Every time I run the code it returns the aforementioned error, which I have isolated to the onChangeText line.

I am pretty new to JS and React Native and I've tried all that I can think of, so I turning to the advice of others.

I hope I'm just forgetting something simple but any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will not issue an error:

```
onChangeText = {(text) => { this.props.data.text = text }}
```

It is an anti-pattern, however, to assign props data...
See:

- [Can I update a component's props in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939623/can-i-update-a-components-props-in-react-js)
- https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

When using typescript if you have named a component file .ts instead of .tsx this will raise a typescript error.  Rename your file to .tsx