# Material-table TypeError: Cannot add property tableData, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui, material-table

I'm using `meterial-table` with `React`. I'm trying to assign data from an array coming from an api like this

```html
<MaterialTable
  columns={columns}
  data={rows}
  ...
/>
```

Where `columns` and `rows` are api data. But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot add property tableData, object is not extensible
```

Notably When I use mock hard-coded data, things are working perfectly. After some search, I couldn't find any solution for it, any help?

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1251

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567386/react-cannot-add-property-x-object-is-not-extensible 
- and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible , Found this thread as I am implementing material-table using redux, it works in my storybook story as I use the mocked data directly, but in development I use the mocked data via the redux store and got the same error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `material-table` or `React`. Most probably this is related to your api response having `Object.preventExtensions()` applied on it for some reason, maybe this is an `Axios` behavior. So when `material-table` is trying to add an `id` field to each object, it's facing this error.
Although not optimal, try to copy your api data to a new array of objects so `material-table` can modify them, e.g:

```js
const editable = rows.map(o => ({ ...o }));
```

```html
<MaterialTable
  columns={columns}
  data={editable}
  ...
/>
```

> Note that I didn't use `rows.map(o => o)` as this will copy the array with the same objects references

**EDIT**:
It's worth mentioning that using *spread operator* or *Object.assign* will only give a shallow copy, i.e. will not copy nested objects. One work-around for this is to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. Please note that this would cause some data loss, other alternatives are on this answer:
[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: worth noting if using this approach, "you only get shallow copies", it might be what you want, or it might not =)   https://2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html#pitfall%3A-cloning-is-always-shallow

Answer (score 24):

You are most likely using `immer` or a library that uses `immer` under the hood (like `@reduxjs/toolkit`). `immer` uses `Object.freeze` to make the objects it produces immutable.

`material-table` modifies its own props (which is a very ugly antipattern). When libraries break rules, they won't work with libraries that try to enforce them.

There is no way to unfreeze an object that has been frozen, but you have a couple of options:

1. Find a way to disable freezing in the immer instance (check out the API docs of whatever you think might have frozen your state).
2. Override `Object.freeze` making it do nothing (very hacky, should be avoided - and yet it might be your best shot here):

```js
window.Object.freeze = function(obj) { return obj }
```

3. Clone/deep copy your state before passing it to `MaterialTable`. This is also far from ideal, especially if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion/explanation. I had exactly the same problem using `immer`. Thankfully, `immer` indeed provides a functionality to disable freezing:
`import { setAutoFreeze } from 'immer';
setAutoFreeze(false);`

Answer (score 3):

import { setAutoFreeze } from 'immer';
setAutoFreeze(false);

worked for me.
material table should consider an api that plays well with immer

Comment: Thanks. Where do you call this if using Redux Toolkit?

Comment: you setAutoFreeze to false globally, or before you start using immer

Answer (score 3):

I got this error while passing the array data in the `Material Data Table`
I was using `reduxjs/toolkit`

As the object are not modifiable ,due to internal implementation of `Object.freeze()` by

**reduxjs/toolkit**

```
 const {cycleList}=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSelector(state=>state.cycleSlice)));
```

I used above method to create a new copy of the  object.

Comment: fwiw, you should put that:  

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(useSelector(state=>state.cycleSlice)))

into its own selector.  That way it will be cached (memoized).

Answer (score 2):

In my case Using "structuredClone" function solved this same issue.

```
var a = useSelector((state) =>state.cusLocChartTable.CusLocationCT);
const cloneData = structuredClone(a.billcity_table);

<ThemeProvider theme={defaultMaterialTheme}>
  <MaterialTable
       columns={[
               { title: 'City', field: 'city' },
               { title: 'Customers', field: 'customers' }
               ]}
               data={cloneData}
               title="Customers"
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: The structuredClone() worked for me thanks.