# cannot add property 1 , onject is not extensible in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

anyone has an idea what causes the ff issue ? I cannot insert new object to a key object in my arrays of objects for example I wanna insert new email to emails at index 1 when I push to that it causes error cannot add property 1 , onject is not extensible in .

Ideads and help would be much appreciated. Thank.s

#code

```
const addEmail = (id: number) => {
    console.log('...RegionalList',RegionalList)
    const regionalList = [...RegionalList];
    const index = regionalList
      .map((prop: IRegionalList) => prop.id)
      .indexOf(id);

    console.log('regionalList[index].emails' , regionalList[index].emails)

    regionalList[index].emails.push({
      emailAddress: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
      fetching: false,
    });
    setRegionalList(regionalList);
  };
```

#object where I am inserting on regionalist arrays of object the value of this variable  const regionalList = [...RegionalList];

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Associate Director of Construction Ops",
        "column": "associateDirectorofConstructionOps",
        "emails": [
            {
                "id": 79,
                "emailAddress": "crawform@raw.com",
                "firstName": "James",
                "lastName": "Crawford"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "CAM Manager",
        "column": "camManager",
        "emails": [
            {
                "id": 77,
                "emailAddress": "jenn.jones4@test.com",
                "firstName": "Jennifer",
                "lastName": "Jones"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

#another snippet

```
 const setEmailValue = (event: any, regionalId: number, index: number) => {
    setRegionalList((prevState: IRegionalList[]) => {
      const newState = prevState.map((prop: IRegionalList) => {
        if (prop.id === regionalId) {
          prop.emails[index] = { emailAddress: event.target.value, id: null };
          return { ...prop };
        }
        return prop;
      });
      return newState;
    });
  }
```

#another snippet

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedRow) {
      console.log('selectedRow' , selectedRow)
      // Set selected row data
      setData({
        regionName: selectedRow['regionName'],
        marketName: selectedRow['marketName'],
        subRegionName: selectedRow['subRegionName'],
      });

      let regional = [...RegionalList];
      for (const k in selectedRow) { 
        regional.map((prop: IRegionalList) => {
          if (prop.column === k) {
            prop.emails = selectedRow[k] ? selectedRow[k] : []
          }
        })
      }
      console.log('regional:', regional);
      setRegionalList(regional);
    }
  }, [selectedRow]);
```

Comment: The array is frozen. You're not supposed to mutate the state anyway. I assume this is React finally enforcing this. Another question for the same thing: [Array.push TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74388436)

Comment: so what is the correct or the answer to it Sir ? right now the freezing is a bit vague for me

Comment: how not to freeze it ?

Comment: DO NOT UNFREEZE IT. YOU ARE REQUIRED TO NOT MUTATE THE STATE.

Comment: Doesn't seems like `regionalList` is a React state. Where is `setRegionalList` defined? Can you share some more code?

Comment: const [RegionalList, setRegionalList] = useState<IRegionalList[]>(RegionalListData);

Comment: Hi Guys , I have update the code on the question please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot mutate the state as in your code above, you have to create and return a new array, so try:

```
const addEmail = (id: number) => {
  setRegionalList(list => list.map(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        emails: [
           ...item.emails,
           {
             emailAddress: '',
             firstName: '',
             lastName: '',
             id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
             fetching: false,
           }
        ]
      }
    }

    return item;
  }))
};
```

Comment: Thank you Sir , I have another question Sir maybe you have an idea with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74389737/cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-0-of-object-object-array