# react issue - Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]' ---

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What causes the ff issue ? Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]' ?

Any idea would be appreacited. Thanks.

#ts code snippet

```
 const [RegionalList, setRegionalList] = useState<IRegionalList[]>(RegionalListData);


 const setEmailValue = (event: any, regionalId: number, index: number) => {
    setRegionalList((prevState: IRegionalList[]) => {
      const newState = prevState.map((prop: IRegionalList) => {
        if (prop.id === regionalId) {
          prop.emails[index] = { emailAddress: event.target.value, id: null };
          return { ...prop };
        }
        return prop;
      });
      return newState;
    });
  }
```

Comment: `prop.emails[index] = { .... }` You are mutating the state here

Comment: if may I ask here about do avoid that ? and how do I fix t hat with my existing code above

Comment: yes Sir cause I need that muration to update the object

Comment: @adiga is right , and I think this will do what you want :
return { ...prop,emails:[...prop.emails.filter( (_,i)=>i !== index ),{ emailAddress: event.target.value, id: null }] }

Comment: can you post it as an answer sir so I can vote? can you integrate it with my sample code above. Thanks.

Comment: where do I put that return statement not clear to me , maybe you can post it as an aswer. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957735/typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-0-of-object-object-array-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the way that I suggest :

```
 const [RegionalList, setRegionalList] = useState<IRegionalList[]>(RegionalListData);


 const setEmailValue = (event: any, regionalId: number, index: number) => {
    setRegionalList((prevState: IRegionalList[]) => {
      const newState = prevState.map((prop: IRegionalList) => {
        if (prop.id === regionalId) {
         return { ...prop,emails:[...prop.emails.filter( (_,i)=>i !== index ),{ emailAddress: event.target.value, id: null }] } 
        }
        return prop;
      });
      return newState;
    });
  }
```

and if you care about order of your list you can do this :

```
    const setEmailValue = (event: any, regionalId: number, index: number) => {
    setRegionalList((prevState: IRegionalList[]) => {
      const newState = prevState.map((prop: IRegionalList) => {
        if (prop.id === regionalId) {
         let emails = prop.emails;
         emails[index] = { emailAddress: event.target.value, id: null };
          return { ...prop,emails }
        }
        return prop;
      });
      return newState;
    });
  }
```

please let me know if it fixed your problem

Comment: Hi Sir , just a question, what makes my existing code wrong ? and why is that it is not allowed to do that mutation ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think this is because you cannot change value of state directly and prop.emails is value of state so you cannot use '=' to change its value 
what I did in second solution was just returning new value for emails and setRegionalList will set it per se

if its not clear I can explain more