# Why does typescript resolve `[]` to `never[]`?

Tags: typescript

To be more specific, if you assign `[]` to a variable, then its type is inferred as `any[]`:

```
// type of x is any[]
const x = []
```

However, if I use `[]` inside an object literal to init a field's value, its type is inferred as `never[]`:

```
// type of x.a is never[]
const x = {
  a : []
}
```

Why is `x.a` is assigned the `never[]` type, instead of `any[]`?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8944 may be related.

Comment: Conceptually it makes sense since there is _never_ any element in the empty array… Maybe slightly impractical, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was due to [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8944): it used to infer `any` and thus widened the type, but this PR changed it to never. It was afterwards suggested to use `unknown[]` instead of never, but this *never* happened.

Comment: But why then in `x = []`, `x` is inferred as `any[]`? Shouldn't type of `x` in `x = []` also be inferred as `never[]`?

Comment: It only goes to never[] with `--strictNullChecks`, but it goes to `never[]` in json objects regardless.