# React re-write componentWillReceiveProps in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am re-writing a component with hooks, and I ran into an interesting challenge, I need to mimick some old behaviour of `componentWillReceiveProps` with the `useEffect` hook.

My old code looks like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {

  const prevLateVal = get(`lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value`, this.props);
  const nextLateVal = get(`lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value`, nextProps); //see here, 
//we use next props

  if (typeof nextLateVal !== 'undefined' && prevLateVal !== nextLateVal) {
    client.connect(bookingId, nextLateVal === null ? 0 : nextLateVal);

  }
}
```

You see, I am initiating a `const` based on nextProps, then in the `if` statement i do a couple checks based on that nextVal, now, I know that we can specify a second argument to `useEffect` to run it only when a prop changes, but what about those checks, how can i implement something similar to `nextProps`?

Comment: Can't you do that check inside the function's body before the return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create custom hook:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.prevLateVal = value;
  });
  return ref.prevLateVal;
}
```

and get it used in `useEffect()`

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const currentLateValue = get(`lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value`, props)
    const prevLateVal = usePrevious(currentLateValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(prevLateVal !== currentLateValue) {
         // process here
        }
    }, [currentLateValue]) // This will be executed only if currentLateValue changes.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `useRef` to save the prev props, and use `useEffect` to run when props change, something like this :

```
function MyComponent(props) {

  const prevProps = useRef(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    const prevLateVal = get(`lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value`, prevProps.current);
    const nextLateVal = get(`lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value`, props);

    if (typeof nextLateVal !== 'undefined' && prevLateVal !== nextLateVal) {
      client.connect(bookingId, nextLateVal === null ? 0 : nextLateVal);
    }    

    prevProps.current = props;
  }, [props, bookingId]);

  return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

Comment: it will run on every render and not on props change, also considering the logic, it should run only on specific object attribute change

Comment: I added props to the second param to useEffect

Comment: It's still buggy because you assuming props reference is changing

Comment: Well props are immutable , aren't they ?

Comment: immutable inside the component, but its father may change attribute and not the reference

Answer (score 3):

With the current logic, you want to fire a side-effect only on `lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value` change:

```
const Component = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('prop lateMinutes changed');
    // ...
  }, [props[`lateMinutes[${bookingId}].value`]);
  return ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need hooks to handle prerender lifecycle.
Just put the things in the functional component before returning JSX as the function itself is equivalent to render method of class based component.