# Best practice in assigning a new key/value pair into a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

Im using React. and trying to assign an new key value. pair into the object. So first it goes through an if check and if it meets the requirement, I want to add the key value 'author'

```
if (field.component === 'Author') {
      this.props.writer.config.payload.name = 'Jefferson';
      console.log(this.props)
    }
```

There are some online articles that tell me to do this way and others that tell me to do Object.assign. Basically though, I just want to add the 'name':'Jefferson' into the object.

Comment: Is it an object stored in state? If so you don't want to add the property directly as it mutates the state in place, you should instead pass a new object with the added property to setState

Comment: nope, its not stored in a state :) @pilchard

Comment: Are trying to mutate the state of parent component?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24943743/1964636

Mutating props in a child component is an anti pattern,
You may want to pass a function as props that can [lift state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in the child component.

Once you modify the state of it's parent component (assuming the props are part of the parent component's state), it will rerender with updated props.